# Get specific column value of last row of a unique user in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table like this

| user | friend | food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | apple |
| Three | Four | hello |
| Three | Two. | hey. |

My desired output is this

| user | friend |
| --- | --- |
| One | Two |
| Three | Two. |

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby_last`:

```
out = df.groupby('user')['friend'].last().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    user friend
0    One    Two
1  Three   Two.
```